# index property forced to string, complains about

Tags: typescript

I have an interface defined as:

```
export interface ICardinalityConfig<T> {
  [key: Extract<keyof T, string>]: [number, number] | number | true;
}
```

but I get an error on on `key`:

> An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.

I would have thought that my `Extract< ..., string >` would have ensured that that condition is met. How do I achieve this goal?

Comment: Is using a `type` an option for your specific case? As you'd be able to use `[key in keyof T]`. Just wondering! 
`export type CardinalityConfig<T> = { [key in keyof T]: [number, number] | number | true };`

Comment: actually yes I can use `type`; wonder why that is possible but not Interface?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is not possible yet as of right now (June 2018). No way to represent index signature as a generic type either.

Only string or number keyword can be used for your case.

[This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7765) was opened in 2016 and is still open

Comment: Wow that's surprising/disappointing. Ok well I'll just use my old fashioned `IDictionary` interface for now and keep hoping that this is addressed at some stage.